# Hibernate "Table not found" error on runtime

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, schema

I have created database successfully with no error and also I added dummy data after creation. Next, I try to get data from database however I have seen an error on console. It tries to create table which was created before.No need to recreate :/ I have searched internet and couldnt find anything related this.

I use MYSQL db, hibernate 4. These 3 classes (Material,MaterialProjectBrief,MaterialProjectImage) dont have any onetomany,manytoone annotations. I have other tables the same structure, they are working well (doing CRUD). I use annotations only I added mapping classed to hibernate.cfg.xml.

(Sorry for writing quickly because I have to leave the office now.

Here is the MaterialProjectImage class.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MaterialProjectImage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3886003470849765887L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="LINK")    
    private String link;

    @Column(name="TITLE")
    private String title;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

Here is the log.

> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000261: Table found: PORTAL.material
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, aboutus, about, sıtemap, vısıon,
>   worklocatıon, mıssıon, customers, rad, goal]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [prımary]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000261: Table found: PORTAL.materialprojectbrief
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, tıtle, shortbrıef, ıconlınk]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [prımary]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: MaterialProjectImage
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000261: Table found: PORTAL.person
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, username, ınfo, ımgpath, name, role,
>   password]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [prımary]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000261: Table found: PORTAL.project
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, faq, tıtle, url, ınstallatıon]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [prımary]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000261: Table found: PORTAL.projectwebview
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, ıntro, ımglınk, project_id, type]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_9qlhqdt00j5a5hknep10wu44c]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_9qlhqdt00j5a5hknep10wu44c, prımary]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000261: Table found: PORTAL.project_document
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [document_id, project_id]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_6gwm4ft0jihnaprel3uem1or6,
>   fk_ctnt2crdturw4k3xc5w4r5571]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_6gwm4ft0jihnaprel3uem1or6,
>   uk_6gwm4ft0jihnaprel3uem1or6, fk_ctnt2crdturw4k3xc5w4r5571]
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
>
> INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: MaterialProjectImage
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
>
> ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table MaterialProjectImage (id
>   integer not null auto_increment, LINK varchar(255), TITLE
>   varchar(255), primary key (id))
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
>
> ERROR: Table 'materialprojectimage' already exists
>
> 22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
>
> INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it is case sensitivity.  As per the MySQL documentation:

How table and database names are stored on disk and used in MySQL is affected by the lower_case_table_names system variable, which you can set when starting mysqld. lower_case_table_names can take the values shown in the following table. On Unix, the default value of lower_case_table_names is 0. On Windows the default value is 1. On Mac OS X, the default value is 2.

Value   Meaning
0   Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement. Name comparisons are case sensitive. You should not set this variable to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive file names (such as Windows or Mac OS X). If you force this variable to 0 with --lower-case-table-names=0 on a case-insensitive file system and access MyISAM tablenames using different lettercases, index corruption may result.
1   Table names are stored in lowercase on disk and name comparisons are not case sensitive. MySQL converts all table names to lowercase on storage and lookup. This behavior also applies to database names and table aliases.
2   Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement, but MySQL converts them to lowercase on lookup. Name comparisons are not case sensitive. This works only on file systems that are not case sensitive! InnoDB table names are stored in lowercase, as for lower_case_table_names=1.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Looking at your error logs it seems highly likely:

22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata

**INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: MaterialProjectImage**

22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute

ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table MaterialProjectImage (id integer not null auto_increment, LINK varchar(255), TITLE varchar(255), primary key (id))

22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute

**ERROR: Table 'materialprojectimage' already exists**

22.Kas.2013 20:17:05 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute

INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete

Comment: Thanks FYI. I appreciated.In addition,I suspect a little bit about case sensitivity but I dont know where to look and what to do. Moreover, I don't set name comparision to set 0. I am running on Windows @mohr_michael_a.Tomorrow I have to go to office to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem by adding **@Table(name="material")** annotation under the **@Entity** annotation according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6227484/621951) . Before doing this, I changed the lower_case_table_names however the problem still continued. Then I have realized to add tab annotation. Thanks.