# Cent OS: Hibernate Envers error REVINFO table doesn't exist but revinfo exists

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, centos

revinfo in small letter working correctly on local and our 2 previous different server but i have new server that doesn't working gives error REVINFO doesn't exist

previous server config :

```
OS : Cent OS 6.5
mysql : 5.5.40
hibernate jar: 4.1.7final
jdk 1.7
```

current server config :

```
OS : Cent OS 6.5
mysql : 5.5.40
hibernate jar: 4.1.7final
jdk 1.7
```

Local

```
Os : windows
mysql : 5.5.40
hibernate jar: 4.1.7final
jdk 1.7
```

both .war file are same

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb_trunk" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="in.demo.server.datamodel" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to try to provide some additional property `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` to your hibernate properties, to make your application behave similar in different environements.

You can read about it in [java doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html) for `NamingStrategy` interface. It has yet some available implementations: [DefaultNamingStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/DefaultNamingStrategy.html) and [ImprovedNamingStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html), you can choose one of them. Or you can create your own implementation.

Comment: i didnt set hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy property in my applicationContext.xml

Comment: @VishnuKatpure yes, you didn't. But hibernate under different OS can behave differently if this property was not provided. Take a look at this question, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218713/hibernate-scheme-naming-differs-between-os

Comment: as i mentioned os ,mysql version are same on previous and current server

Comment: by doing patch work RENAME TABLE revinfo TO REVINFO ; working correctly

Comment: @VishnuKatpure If all your environment was the same, you had never got this exception. OS-specific behaviour is just an example. Anything could lead to this, may be Java version, may be application version or something else. To prevent this, you have to set the naming strategy.

Answer (score 0):

windows mysql default case insensitive so i have added

```
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

in

**/etc/mysql/my.cnf** file for cent OS.

refer for more in detail https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59407/how-to-make-mysql-table-name-case-insensitive-in-ubuntu